# unable to import flask_login despite being installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have searched around and seen some similar questions, but nothing that helps with my issue. I am learning Flask and following a video on Flask Authentication.

I am working from a venv specific to this project, running python 3.10 and have installed Flask-Login:

```
(.venv) >> pip3 freeze
bcrypt==4.0.1
click==8.1.3
dnspython==2.2.1
email-validator==1.3.0
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-Bcrypt==1.0.1
Flask-Login==0.6.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.2
Flask-WTF==1.0.1
greenlet==2.0.1
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
SQLAlchemy==1.4.45
Werkzeug==2.2.2
WTForms==3.0.1
```

I'm just at the start of this project so my code is very simple:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin 

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
db.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def home(): 
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login(): 
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/register')
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The problem is that VSCode doesn't see flask_login as being able to import despite being installed in the proper venv where my other imports are also located. The below is from the Problems tab:

```
Import "flask_login" could not be resolved
```

Nothing I have found online seems to help with my situation. I have seen some that suggest the editor is just having problems and to restart - which I did but did not help. I uninstalled and reinstalled and also had no success.

I am not sure what I am missing...

Comment: Try `pip show flask_login` to see details

Comment: I do that and it shows it is in the correct location, just like the other imports but I am still unable to import it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Choose the correct interpreter.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> Python:Select Interpreter

- Select an interpreter with the `flask_login` package installed
- Choose the interpreter you want to use

  Create a new terminal activation environment

  Install the `flask_login` package for the currently selected interpreter

Or you can use the following code to print out the current interpreter path, and then copy the path to install the `flask_login` package for the current interpreter

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! It's very strange, I had the correct interpreter selected, I had the correct environment created and activated where flask_login was installed. When checking manually, the package was there, but for some reason the interpreter could not see it... I completely restarted again doing the exact same steps and it works as expected. Not sure the cause still but I really appreciate the additional insight!